# Submitting data to Django web application?

Tags: python, django, http, web-applications, web

I'm interested in starting a new project to learn Django. The basic idea: I'd like to be able to compose generic content decorated in markdown (blog posts etc..), and automatically publish this to the website with some sort of script.

I'm new to web programming, so I'm wondering what mechanisms should be used to facilitate the transfer of the markdown text. What HTTP action should be used for something like this (POST or GET)? How can I authenticate with the Django app before publishing (was hoping for some kind of public/private key auth)?  What command line tool would you recommend I use to submit the data, curl, wget, magic? What kind of security issues should I be aware of?

Looking for someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm aware of the admin site and specifically do not want to use it. I'm interested in using the api as a communication layer, and am using a blog as a simple example to understand the protocols. It's more of a learning experiment than a functional site.

Comment: Take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/django-pgpauth/ for a key-based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I would just get comfortable with the automatic admin interface and add your content there. Then you can use [`django.contrib.markup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/markup/) to parse the Markdown.

The admin is one of the best parts about Django. Once you're experienced with it, you can whip up something like what you mentioned above within a couple hours or less.

Answer (score 0):

Django is providing a easy to create admin site.
You can enable it by uncommenting the corresponding line in urls.py.

Also check these links. It will be helpful to get start with admin site in django.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01

A simple blog app example is here
http://lightbird.net/dbe/